# Angular 2: data returned from Firebase aren't mapped on my array of object

Tags: angular, firebase, angular2-services, angular2-http, angular2-observables

I'm fetching data from Firebase with Angular 2 using Observables, but, even if i get the result from the http call, i can't map the returned object on my entity.

I want to map into an Array of Recipe. A recipe is:

```
export class Recipe {
    constructor(public name: string,
        public description: string,
        public imagePath: string,
        public ingredients: Ingredient[]) {
    }
}
```

The component class that contains the Array of Recipes and the first call to the service responsible of fetching data plus the subscriber is:

```
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
  recipes: Recipe[] = [];

  constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
    this.recipeService.recipesChanged.subscribe(
      (recipes: Recipe[]) => this.recipes = recipes
    );
  }
}
```

While the method for fetching data in the service is:

```
  fetchData() {
    return this.http.get('https://...firebaseio.com/...json')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .subscribe(
      (data: Recipe[]) => {
        this.recipes = data;
        console.log(data);
        this.recipesChanged.emit(this.recipes);
      });
```

Data is correctly retrieved, but is not cast on my Recipe[], infact the returned object is in this form:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
   [
      0: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         description: "Gioco",
         imagePath: "http://....png",
         ingredients: [
            0: {
               [functions]: ,
               __proto__: { },
               amount: 50,
               name: "Silicone",
               Symbol(observable)_g.ds6ymh8xmrz: undefined,
               Symbol(rxSubscriber)_h.ds6ymh8xmrz: undefined
            },
            1: {
               [functions]: ,
               __proto__: { },
               amount: 30,
               name: "Plastica",
               Symbol(observable)_g.ds6ymh8xmrz: undefined,
               Symbol(rxSubscriber)_h.ds6ymh8xmrz: undefined
            },
            length: 2
         ],
         name: "Lego",
         Symbol(observable)_g.ds6ymh8xmrz: undefined,
         Symbol(rxSubscriber)_h.ds6ymh8xmrz: undefined
      },
      1: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         description: "Peluche",
         imagePath: "http://....png",
         name: "Orsacchiotto",
         Symbol(observable)_g.ds6ymh8xmrz: undefined,
         Symbol(rxSubscriber)_h.ds6ymh8xmrz: undefined
      },
      length: 2
   ]
```

How can it be solved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Firebase does not store data as arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), so the HTTP response will be a JSON object. And if you are going to use a simple cast, you should use an `interface` - not a `class`.

Answer (score 3):

Output() variables are not intended to use in services, you should map the response and return the Observable as such

```
fetchData() :Observable<Recipes> {
    return this.http.get('https://...firebaseio.com/...json')
      .map((response: Response) => <Recipe[]>response.json())
      });
```

In your onInit

```
this.recipeService.getRecipes().subscribe(recipes => {
       this.recipes = recipes;
});
```

Also, when you are using reference types to serve as models use **interfaces**

```
export interface Recipe {
        name: string;
        description: string;
        imagePath: string;
        ingredients: Ingredient[];

}
```

Comment: "subscribe" does not exists on type "Recipe[]".

Comment: Why are you going to subscribe the recipe type

Comment: I followed your example: "this.recipeService.getRecipes().subscribe(recipes => ..."

Comment: The correct instruction in "onInit" of the component is: this.recipeService.fetchData().subscribe(r => { this.recipes = r });

Comment: I have to explain that this is an exercise from a course and the tutor put the input/output variable "recipes" just because it started from fixed data. I won't put output data in service, too, in normale case, but i wanted to make it work as it is. With your example i have to make the variable as public, so i can syncronize when data comes to component. Nothing wrong for a mere exercise...